# copy.copy(object) returns an object with id == None during tests?

Tags: django, copy

I am new to Django and Python, building my first app using TDD...  I wanted to copy an instance of `Task`, a model object.  I used the following code, which works correctly during the tests:

```
import copy

class Task(models.Model): 
    ...
    def make_copy(self):
       new_task = copy.copy(self)
       new_task.save()
       return new_task
```

But when running this code 'normally', in the server, I noticed it was not working: no new object was created.  I found out I had to add `new_task.id = None` just before saving, and I understand the reason for this...

But if `copy.copy` does not know about Django and thus will not change the `id` itself, why is it the case that the object returned has `id == None` during the tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your test case is not fully matching the usage in your "normal" use case.

The `id` field is set for objects that exist in the database.  If you pass your `make_copy()` method an object with `id` set, it will appear to fail because it's not making a new database object, it's just saving an existing object (through the Python copy, with an existing `id`).

I'd guess your test case is passing `Task` objects to `make_copy()` with `id` of None (and therefore *appearing* to work), while in "normal" usage, the objects are coming in with `id` set.  (You could test this hypothesis with a simple print or assert statement).

One simple solution might be to set `id` to `None` right after your copy operation.  That way, a new database object is always created.

Finally, someone else with the same situation:  http://www.nerdydork.com/copy-model-object-in-django.html

Comment: That was it! The `Task` object that I create at the start of the test was not saved... Thanks!